# How to check which physical address belongs to which NUMA node?

Tags: virtual-memory, numa

I have some physical addresses, which I want to check which NUMA node it belongs to.

I've been searching, and I've found some ways to check the NUMA node with *virtual address* (e.g., `move_pages`), but not with a physical address. Maybe the second to best way is to check the `pagemap` to reverse translate physical to virtual address?

Comment: In **/proc/zoneinfo**, **start_pfn**  indicates the physical start address of each zone for each node.